# Symfony2.8 PHPUnit parsing YAML error

Tags: symfony, phpunit

I want to write a simple test that checks that a page is well loaded :

```
public function testShowHomepage()
{
    $client = self::createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertTrue($client->getResponse()->isSuccessful());
}
```

This is my homepage and it works in dev and prod environments.

I changed the function above to have a look at the rendering :

```
public function testShowHomepage()
{
    $client = self::createClient();
    $client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertEquals('o', $client->getResponse()->getContent());
}
```

Surprise ! The server returns a status 500 page with this error :

> The file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml must contain a YAML array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml (which is being imported from /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml). (500 Internal Server Error)

I parsed my routing.yml but can't find any problem. You can take a look at this file [here](https://github.com/steph-del/eveg/blob/master/src/eveg/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml).

The stack trace :

```
[1] Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: The file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml" must contain a YAML array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml (which is being imported from "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml").
at n/a
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php line 133

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('@evegAppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml', 'be_simple_i18n', false, '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 174

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImport(object(RouteCollection), array('resource' => '@evegAppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml', 'type' => 'be_simple_i18n'), '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 94

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml', null)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php line 112

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('routing.yml', null, false, '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 174

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImport(object(RouteCollection), array('resource' => 'routing.yml'), '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 94

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml', null)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php line 112

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml', null, false, '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 174

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImport(object(RouteCollection), array('resource' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml'), '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 94

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', 'yaml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php line 45

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', 'yaml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/DelegatingLoader.php line 83

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\DelegatingLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', 'yaml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/Router.php line 54

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router->getRouteCollection()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 387

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->getMatcherDumperInstance()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 298

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->Symfony\Component\Routing\{closure}(object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory.php line 46

at Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory->cache('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php', object(Closure))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 312

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->getMatcher()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 252

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->match('/')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/besimple/i18n-routing-bundle/BeSimple/I18nRoutingBundle/Routing/Router.php line 103

at BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle\Routing\Router->match('/')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 156

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php line 61

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 184

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 46

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 140

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3212

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3182

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3336

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2540

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php line 79

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest(object(Request))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php line 131

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest(object(Request))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php line 315

at Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request('GET', '/')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php line 13

at eveg\AppBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest->testShowHomepage()
    in  line 

at ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(object(DefaultControllerTest), array())
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php line 1103

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php line 954

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php line 701

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(object(DefaultControllerTest))
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php line 909

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php line 728

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php line 487

at PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), array('listGroups' => false, 'listSuites' => false, 'loader' => null, 'useDefaultConfiguration' => true, 'loadedExtensions' => array(), 'notLoadedExtensions' => array(), 'configuration' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/phpunit.xml', 'testSuffixes' => array('Test.php', '.phpt')), true)
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php line 188

at PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(array('../phpunit-5.7.5.phar', '-c', 'app/', 'src/eveg/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php'), true)
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php line 118

at PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar line 581
```

---

```
[2] InvalidArgumentException: The file "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml" must contain a YAML array.
at n/a
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/besimple/i18n-routing-bundle/BeSimple/I18nRoutingBundle/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 132

at BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml', 'be_simple_i18n')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php line 112

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('@evegAppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml', 'be_simple_i18n', false, '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 174

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImport(object(RouteCollection), array('resource' => '@evegAppBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.yml', 'type' => 'be_simple_i18n'), '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 94

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing.yml', null)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php line 112

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('routing.yml', null, false, '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 174

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImport(object(RouteCollection), array('resource' => 'routing.yml'), '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 94

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml', null)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/FileLoader.php line 112

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\FileLoader->import('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml', null, false, '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 174

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->parseImport(object(RouteCollection), array('resource' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/config/routing_dev.yml'), '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/YamlFileLoader.php line 94

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Loader\YamlFileLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', 'yaml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/Loader/DelegatingLoader.php line 45

at Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', 'yaml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/DelegatingLoader.php line 83

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\DelegatingLoader->load('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/assetic/routing.yml', 'yaml')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Routing/Router.php line 54

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router->getRouteCollection()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 387

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->getMatcherDumperInstance()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 298

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->Symfony\Component\Routing\{closure}(object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(ResourceCheckerConfigCache))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Config/ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory.php line 46

at Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory->cache('/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainerUrlMatcher.php', object(Closure))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 312

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->getMatcher()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Router.php line 252

at Symfony\Component\Routing\Router->match('/')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/besimple/i18n-routing-bundle/BeSimple/I18nRoutingBundle/Routing/Router.php line 103

at BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle\Routing\Router->match('/')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 156

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php line 61

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener->__invoke(object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
    in  line 

at call_user_func(object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 184

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcher.php line 46

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php line 140

at Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3212

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3182

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3336

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true)
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2540

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php line 79

at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest(object(Request))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php line 131

at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest(object(Request))
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php line 315

at Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request('GET', '/')
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/src/eveg/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php line 13

at eveg\AppBundle\Tests\Controller\DefaultControllerTest->testShowHomepage()
    in  line 

at ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(object(DefaultControllerTest), array())
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php line 1103

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest()
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php line 954

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare()
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestResult.php line 701

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run(object(DefaultControllerTest))
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestCase.php line 909

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run(object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/Framework/TestSuite.php line 728

at PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run(object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult))
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/TextUI/TestRunner.php line 487

at PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun(object(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite), array('listGroups' => false, 'listSuites' => false, 'loader' => null, 'useDefaultConfiguration' => true, 'loadedExtensions' => array(), 'notLoadedExtensions' => array(), 'configuration' => '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eveg/app/phpunit.xml', 'testSuffixes' => array('Test.php', '.phpt')), true)
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php line 188

at PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run(array('../phpunit-5.7.5.phar', '-c', 'app/', 'src/eveg/AppBundle/Tests/Controller/DefaultControllerTest.php'), true)
    in phar:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar/phpunit/TextUI/Command.php line 118

at PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main()
    in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phpunit-5.7.5.phar line 581
```

Any idea ?

I'm running Symfony 2.8, PHPUnit 5.7.4 and PHP 5.6.27.

Thank's

Comment: Your YAML file looks ok. Could it be that there’s some filter in effect which modifies your routing.yml and returns a bad value?

Comment: No, there is no event that modifies the routing.yml file. If so, I couldn't access to my pages (the Symfony debug bar doesn't any routing warning). I'm investigating about PHPUnit workflow. Does PHPUnit it parse Yaml file through Symfony components or by itself ?

Comment: PHPunit doesn’t even know what YAML is. I assume you’re using Symfony’s WebTestCase, which loads the kernel etc. for you. Can you please post a complete stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Ok. I added the stack trace in the post. The BeSimple/I18nRoutingBundle override the default YAML loader and throw the error.

Comment: The problem comes from the BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle. Updating this bundle to the latest version (beta) close the issue.